# 'Fragment' is defined but never used no-unused-vars warning with React app using ESLint

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am fairly new to React and I've created a new app using the `create-react-app` tool and started to play around with it. When ever I run my app, I get following warning:

```
Compiled with warnings.

./src/index.js
  Line 1:  'Fragment' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

The following code is in my **App.js**:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Header from "./Layouts/Header";
import Footer from "./Layouts/Footer";

export default class extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Header />
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <Footer />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Which is used like this in my **index.js** (main entry point):

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import App from "./Components/App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
registerServiceWorker();
```

And I have installed the react plugin for ESLint and this is the configuration I am using in my **.eslintrc**

```
{
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 2
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"]
}
```

Any ideas how to resolve this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the line

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
```

in your `index.js` file, but you aren't using `Fragment` anywhere in that file.  You can fix this by changing the import line to:

```
import React from "react";
```

Edit: Note the identical `import` in your `App.js` file is perfectly valid, as you *are* using `Fragment` in that file.

Comment: Aha, I see what I did wrong here. Thanks for pointing this out.